# Complex numbers confused!!

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

If you give me a complex number say $z=2+3i$, then I can easily find $\text{Im}(z)=3$ and $\text{Re}(z)=2$ but when this polar coordinates stuff came, I lost my head!

So say $z=r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)$. What is $\text{Im}(z)$ and $\text{Re}(z)$ ?

Comment: Re$(z)=r\cos\theta=2$

Comment: @حكيمالفيلسوفالضائع I'm not sure, but I kept the original notation. Aren't both of these common?

Comment: @user2345215 I'm not sure, but I prefer the mathcal style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just expand and you'll get: $$z=\underbrace{r\cos\theta}_{\displaystyle\Re(z)}+i\underbrace{\,r\sin\theta}_{\displaystyle\Im(z)}.$$

I hope this helps. 
Best wishes, $\mathcal H$akim.

Comment: I'm so stupid!! that was too simple!

Answer (score -1):

$r[\cos(\theta)] = \operatorname{Re}(z)$, $r[\sin(\theta)] = \operatorname{Im}(z)$